# Como alinhar div ao lado de duas rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Quero deixar a ultima imagem centralizada no meio das duas rows porem não sei como fazer utilizei uma `margin-top: 15%;` foi para o centro como eu quero porem a segunda row desceu e não ficou perto da primeira e iniciando no final do ultima imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="../assets/img/per.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="../assets/img/per.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="../assets/img/per.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 15%;">
    <img src="../assets/img/per.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="../assets/img/per.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="../assets/img/per.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="../assets/img/per.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: isso é padrão? ou pode variar?

Comment: Padrão, no caso so ira variar para celular em telas sm

Comment: porque não coloca num `row`com 12 colunas e alinhamento center não resolveria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui fazer com `transform: translateY`. Criei a classe .vertical, e coloquei na `<div>` que vc quer alinhar verticalmente.

```
.vertical {
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

***Execute o Snipper em "Página Toda" para ver funcionando direitinho. Pois ele está com as classes do Bootstrap de acordo com o código que vc postou...***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
 
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
           .vertical{
              transform: translateY(50%);
           }
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/50/150" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/50/150" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/50/150" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3 vertical">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/50/150" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/50/150" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/50/150" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/50/150" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

OBS: Para não dar erro em telas diferentes vc pode colocar nas div os tamanhos para cada tela **(col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3)**, tipo assim:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-ms-3 col-xs-3 vertical">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/50/150" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Pode melhorar a sua resposta? Tem um problema nela :)

Comment: Coloca a classe dentro de `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { }` porque senão a div que vc alinhou vai ficar mal posicionada quando a tela for menor que 768px

Comment: Sim @dvd é pq ele está usando apenas a classe `col-md` se ele usar col-md / col-sm / col-xs na div não da erro. Ele teria que mudar em todas as @media na verdade. Vou dar uma editada lá.

Comment: É porque quando a tela for menor que 769px não precisa mais dessa classe de alinhamento. Senão vai ficar um buraco entre duas imagens.

Comment: então @dvd como eu faço?

Comment: @dvd eu estava tentando aqui com o `@media` mas não consegui simular o erro. Só consegui usando as medidas do Grid na div, conforme atualização que fiz. :/

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo eu atualizei a minha resposta, da uma olhada na **Observação** logo após o Snippet

Comment: Então marco qual das duas respostas como certo?

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo Não Everton, deixa a do Hugo marcada, ele respondeu corretamente, só esqueceu desse detalhe.

Comment: Nãaooo! rs... tava certa antes... agora ficou até pior rs

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do [@hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl) está correta, mas faltou colocar um **@media rule**. Como o site é responsivo, o Bootstrap transforma todas as colunas em 1 só quando a tela for menor que **769px**.

Então, complementando a resposta do [@hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl), o CSS ficaria assim:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .vertical{
      transform: translateY(50%);
   }
}
```

Veja o buraco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Eu colocaria em um container uma div de col-md-12 para preencher a tela e depois seguiria com as div com class col-md-6 cada (caso realmente seja só duas divs).

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
<img src="#" alt="sua imagem">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Aqui seria suas duas colunas em um ROW (já é mais que suficiente)</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Pode tambem alinhas com CSS ou de uma forma mais bruta usando o atributo style="text-align:center"; para a imagem geralmente uso isso.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Alias se eu entendi bem seria util criar um container que armazena suas Rows então tera uma row tamanho 12 e duas rows tamanho 6.